# How do I style states of a Pivot's HeaderTemplate?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

How do change the visual state of the TextBlock by hooking into the same states that [PanelHeaderItem template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx) uses?

Code Sample:

```
<Pivot>
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Text" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                <TextBlock x:Key="Text" Text="{Binding}" Opacity="0.5" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

The `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` tag is my failed attempt at trying to change the state of the TextBlock using the same VisualStates that are used in the [PanelHeaderItem template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx). If there's a way to target the TextBlock from within the [PanelHeaderItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx)'s `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups`, that would also work, but I don't know how.

Ideally looking for a pure XAML way to do this (no C#).

Comment: Do you want a textblock have the same effect with pivotheaderitem or want to custom the pivortheaderitem's style?

Comment: If you put your TextBlock inside the PivotHeader content template you can acheive by editing PivotHeaderStyle. Is that ok?

Comment: I want to be able to specify different HeaderTemplates for Pivots and have the VisualStateManager of PivotHeaderItem change certain properties that are the same across them all. @LovetoCode, if it's possible to specify a different PivotHeaderTemplate per Pivot, then that should work...how can that be done?

Comment: Different header templates means how much different? Can you tell what controls should be there in each template and which properties to change? You can  update your question

Comment: What's per pivot. What do you really want? Custom one pivot's head? In one page you have many pivots and you want them are all different headeritemstyle? If you want different headeritemstyle one page per pivot, it is impossible. Please detail your question.

Answer (score 0):

To change the properties of Textblock you can use [RelativeSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) in binding. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Opacity="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Opacity}"/>` In this Binding I'm binding ContentPresenter Opacity to Textblock Opacity.

```
<Pivot>
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Opacity="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Opacity}"/>
              </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
....
</Pivot>
```

In below style of PivotHeader i'm changing Opacity to 1 and Forground to Red in `Selected` `VisualState`

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                     Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

   <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
            <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemMargin}" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                        <Grid
          x:Name="Grid"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="XamlAutoFontFamily"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                                    <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight"/>
                                    <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full"/>
                                    <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings"/>
                                </Style>
                                <Style x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}">
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="Unselected" To="UnselectedLocked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                        <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked" To="Unselected" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                 Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                 Duration="0" To="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                     Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter
            x:Name="ContentPresenter" Opacity="0.5"
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
            FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```